# What is a word for an employee of a company that deals with community-related matters?

Tags: terminology, business-language

As in someone who interacts with the greater community and enforces an ethical code within the company. We came up with a few possibilities like "Crime Prevention Officer" or "Public Liaison Officer", but we are not entirely sure.

My uncle works in customer service for a utility company and his colleague stumbled across a house that had about 10 tenants in the past month. After discussing it, the colleague raised it with management and the manager didn't want to do anything, so my uncle would like to put in a formal request to get one of these officers in the company. However, he feels that management will pay more attention if proper terminology is used.

Comment: Unclear about the role, I would have said public relations based on the title...what would this person do about the house with 10 tenants, for example?

Comment: They would make sure proper contact is established with the police force and ensure that the company's legitimacy is maintained through the process.

Comment: I should have asked, what is the ethical problem having 10 tenants?  I can see it being a nightmare for billing, but that is a practical, not ethical, concern.

Comment: The feeling was that the property was being used for illegitimate purposes. A lot of things in the UK require proof of address and only living in a house for 3 days would give you the ability to give that.

Comment: In the US it would be very unusual for those two functions to be united in one officer. Managements want to maintain control over ethics matters, and would rather keep the CR right hand in the dark about what the ethics left hand is doing, until the company's posture has been decided. If no one in the company is specifically charged with ethics oversight, I suggest your uncle address himself to the chief legal officer, who will at least have a sound sense of the company's legal responsibility.

Comment: I think this question is "Unclear". Is the uncle concerned about overcrowding? That's illegal in the UK and would normally be addressed by the relevant local authority (district/city council, etc.). Illegal immigrants are a matter for the UK Border Agency, but you can just contact the Home Office if you want. If *health* is a potential issue you might consider just calling 999 - I seriously doubt they'd accuse you of wasting police time in such circumstances.

Comment: Is it that your uncle wants to know what the ethics/compliance function within his employing company is called -- because he's not happy that his manager has acted ethically? It could be anything: mine (an American company) has an Ethics Officer within the legal department, which is called the Office of the General Counsel. I wonder if this should actually be migrated to Workplace.SE; but I suspect the answer lies within the company's internal directory, or employee policy documents. Anybody's guess is just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're looking for a role that's responsible for ensuring that both employees and the firm as a whole comply with both internal and external rules.

The most common role title is probably *Compliance Officer*, used primarily in financial firms, or firms whose external concerns mostly involve regulators.

Another title is *Trust and Safety Director* (or *Officer*), used more in tech firms, or those whose external concerns tend to be the well-being, privacy, or legal rights of users or customers.

Answer (score 1):

Community outreach coordinator

Comment: Does this address the ethical aspect? I thought community outreach coordinators were more about doing events in the community and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

*Ombudsman* may be a suitable term here. The New Oxford American dictionary defines *ombudsman* as

> [A]n official appointed to investigate individuals' complaints against
>   maladministration, especially that of public authorities.

so both the community relations aspect and the ethics enforcement aspect would be covered by this.

Comment: That isn't at all what an *ombudsman* does, in my understanding. Could you explain why or by what definition you believe it applies?

Comment: It was a prompt to edit your answer to provide an explanation :). As you should know from other SE sites, it is not enough to provide an answer; you should always explain why you propose an answer, including suitable references.

Comment: Fair enough. I’ve incorporated comment into an expanded answer.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit of a stretch, but *Code Enforcement Officer* is used in the US to describe a person whose job it is to inspect something to make sure it meets code (legal) standards. It's applicable to things like electrical/plumbing/hvac safety and compliance, hazardous environments, disposal requirements, occupancy, health, etc. It could be a good blanket term if you're looking for someone who would cover many different aspects of compliance and ethics.